Differential inequation $f'(x) > f(x)/x$
I am interested in the following differential inequation, for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:
$$f'(x) > \dfrac{f(x)}{x}$$
I only care about this being satisfied at infinity, ie for $x \gg 1$. Hence, if a function $f$ does not satisfy it for low values of $x$, but does for $r \sim \infty$, that's fine by me.
The equality case is when $f$ is linear, ie $f = ax$ at infinity. Am I then right in assuming that the inequality is satisfied whenever $f'$ is such that $f'(x)$ is superior to any constant for $x$ big enough? In other words, $f'(x) \to \infty$.
I can prove that this condition is necessary. There is some 'differential inequality fundamental lemma', which is that, if a function $g$ satisfies a differential equation $g' = F(g,x)$, for $F$ locally Lipschitz and continuous, and $f' > F(f,x)$, then as soon as I find a point $x_0$ such that $g(x_0) \leq f(x_0)$, I have $g(x) < f(x)$ for all $x > x_0$.
Hence, in my scenario, since $f'$ must be bigger than any constant, the condition $f'(x) \to \infty$ is necessary. It can be rephrased as "$f$ must grow to infinity faster than $x$".
Is this condition sufficient? Can I already conclude the claim ? Or am I missing something?
Note: I would assume that I'm done. I have checked it to be true for $f$ a polynomial, an exponential, or a function of the form $x^n \ln(x)$
But I do not know how to assert it in the general case.

I don't know if this helps, but geometrically, you can picture this condition as saying that the tangent line at any point on the graph $\bigl(x, f(x)\bigr)$ has slope greater than the line through the origin and that point. If the function is twice differentiable, this is equivalent to the function being concave up. In other words, at every point on the graph, the tangent line intercepts the $x$-axis at a positive value.

That's quite nice indeed! Thank you :)

Actually, coming back to say this is exactly the graphical visualization I needed! Nice one. (Though I think you meant convex, but it doesn't matter)

Isn't it clearly not necessary? For example, for $x>1$, $f(x) = x-1/x$ has $f'(x) < 2$ (so $f'(x)$ does not grow arbitrarily large) but $f'(x) = 1+1/x^2 > f(x)/x$ for all $x$.

"Is this condition sufficient?" It is almost sufficient.
"Can I already conclude? Or am I missing something?" You are missing negative numbers.
Consider this Image :

We do not care what occurs at low $x$ , while at large $x$ , we have $dy/dx$ larger than $y/x$.
When we invert the Image , we will get negative values & we will have $y/x$ larger than $dy/dx$.
Hence we want to impose the Criteria that $dy/dx$ larger than $|y|/x$ which handles that.
The Inequality is then satisfied when $|y|$ is larger than linear.

Checks out. With this, and Sammy Black's comment, I've got it! :) Thank you!
